# How to add a progress bar in jssor slider (just like the one in revolution slider)?

Tags: jquery, slider, progress-bar, jssor

Hi I am building a slider on my site using Jssor Slider (with jQuery).

I have seen a progress bar (timer bar) on revolution slider. example here - http://htmlstream.com/preview/unify-v1.5/page_home2.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the following 2 steps,

1. Add static element to 'slides' container as progress element.

   ```
   <div u="slides" ...>
       ... 
       <div id="progress-element" u="progress" style="position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0; width: 0%; height: 5px; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); z-index: 100;"></div>
   </div>
   ```
2. Update progress while $JssorSlider$.$EVT_PROGRESS_CHANGE event fires.

   ```
       var progressElement = document.getElementById("progress-element");

       function UpdateProgress(slideIndex, progress, progressBegin, idleBegin, idleEnd, progressEnd) {
           if (progressEnd > 0) {
               var progressPercent = progress / progressEnd * 100 + "%";
               progressElement.style.width = progressPercent;
           }
       }

       jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PROGRESS_CHANGE, UpdateProgress);
   ```

Reference: [Slider with Progress Bar Example](http://www.jssor.com/testcase/slider-with-progress-bar.html)